# How do I hack the blender help button?

Tags: python, linux, button, blender

I do not have/will_not_have constant internet access, and I am a blender noob, so I did the sensible thing and downloaded the offline manual, however, the "help button" will still link to the internet. I'm very insaneley forgetful, also I like my development environments to be self-reliant.

Therefore: I am afraid I may forget I have the manual on my system and attempt to download it a second time, or that I will have to constantly open up file manager just to use it real quick.

All this could be fixed by changing the default URL to the file directory location I have the html doc of said manual within, but I'm also a newb to python and can't find the exact name of the folder nor file that contains the script for the little URL. I do have c++ programming experience as well as a basic comprehension of the command line. All this is driving me nuts; I'm willing to work for the result, but I'm in desperate need of some pointers at the very least, I am much obliged.

Thank You to anyone who took the time to read this!!!

(I have an explanatory screenshot here: {  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4stTAVYtcSVR3I0Z0R3bVR3RjQ/view?usp=drivesdk }(via google drive) (don't have enough rep to post image directly apparently))
[ this is a photo of the button I'm talking about ]

Comment: Not sure if it really serves the question, but since you are looking for the URL to the on-line documentation inside of the Blender's sources, try, from the main Blender sources directory: `find . -name "*py" | xargs grep [url]`. This should output a list of the files where that url appears.

Comment: In short: the "help" button (see attached image) sends you to a URL, do you know where the code containing that specific link is at, so that I can find it and change it?

Comment: K, can do; I will try that tomorrow though, my keyboard isn't backlit, and I relative/roommate who is very sensitive to light and trying to sleep. I honestly didn't expect such a quick response so thank you (I did bother to learn the keys by heart, but my memory really is rather frightening, and I second guess myself while typing at night, which can lead to lots of squinting at the keyboard (this this, is happening from a phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's goal is to find where, in Blender's sources, is called some specific url, say `some_url`.

To find `some_url` in all the python files inside of the `src` directory, you can do the following in bash:

```
$ find src -name "*py" | xargs grep some_url
```

Comment: It did some finageling and I got it to work out great. The .Zip I downloaded was busted, but I got another one, substituted the URL, and now the browser opens right up to it, directly from blender. So I'd call that a happy ending

Comment: @IanSchimnoski Sweet :) But you should remove all your comments (except the last one), because even though you just hit "enter" by accident (which is actually pretty common), it just looks like spam. Nice to have helped you though ;)

Answer (score 1):

While the above/earlier answers were correct enough to help me find the solution, and are therefore good answers (because I wouldn't have been able to do it without them):              a very direct answer is: "go to the: "  ~/blender/scripts/bl_ui " file location. the specific URL I was looking for was in the "space_info.py" file. Use a 'ctrl F ' search within that file (assuming you have opened it in a text editor, and that you have root privileges), find the version of said URL that happens to be nested within code describing how the "help" button operates (It's advisable that one save a back-up before this next step), then replace that URL with the exact file path which leads to your offline html file that you want it to take you to"     those are the steps I followed, so by the bluemoon chance someone else would have the same exact or very similar question: there's my answer, I hope it streamlines your quest

Answer (score -2):

How to Force Blender to Load Local Blender Docs instead external Help Link of url =
"https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/"

HOW I did it.
I downloaded the "blender_manual.zip" file ( Blender 3.3 Version  at the time I tried this Hack) from the URL "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/" which has a link on that page,which is
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/blender_manual_html.zip
(Don't use the EPUB download option (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/blender_manual_epub.zip).
I un-Zipped the downloaded "blender_manual.zip" file into a new folder "BlenderDocs" I made in my root directory ( the drive on which Blender is installed) c:\BlenderDocs and removed the contents of the "html-en-dev-r4466" folder to which it had been unzipped and pasted the contents into the main "c:\BlenderDocs" folder.
Then as adviced in the blog I launched Notepad++ and dragged the file "space_info.py" from the "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_ui" folder into Notepad++ and saved a back-up of it into the folder where you found this notepad text file.
Using Notepad++ save "ALL Types" mode I saved it as "space_info.py.UNCHANGED" for safe keeping to a known folder.
Then I went into " C:\BlenderDocs" folder and double clicked on "index.html" to launch in my Firefox web browser.
I Highlighted the URL indicated in the Firefox URL slot at the top which said "file:///C:/Blender%20Docs/index.html". copy pated into a new notepad.txt file and I changed the statement to
file:///C:/BlenderDocs/index.html
and replaced the statement  "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/" on line 321 of Notepad++ with  "file:///C:/BlenderDocs/index.html" instead.

I changed the "space_info.py" file extension in the "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_ui" folder to "space_info.py.ORIGINAL.WORKING" as a safety precaution.

and from inside Notepad++ I saved the modified "space_info.py" first to my desktop for safe-keeping reference and then copy pasted the same file into the "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_ui" folder with ADMINISTRATION privilege to replace the original.

I launched Blender in the Usual way by double clicking on its Desktop Icon and tested the Help Menu first item. Perfectly the internal Help HTML pack from the BlenderDocs folder was presented to me in my Firefox browser.
All except the External links work. But that is understood as the blender_manual.zip file cannot contain all the vast help material from outside the Help Wiki!
Of course in a clinch you can now change the "space_info.py.ORIGINAL.WORKING" [after deleting "space_info.py" the modified version] back to "space_info.py" and re launch Blender. It will link to the Web based help WIKI.
You can modify the statement at LINE 321 of Notepad++ to any URL for that matter and get blender  HELP to link to that new URL.
I believe This is a handy get local HELP HACK for all Blender Users.